# Codeigniter "anchor" tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in codeigniter framework, I just wanna convert this PHP code into Codeigniter version

```
echo '<td><a rel="facebox" href=useredit.php?emp_id='. $row['emp_id'] .'><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td></a>' ;
```

I saw an example like this

```
echo '<td>' . anchor('user/edit_user/'. $i->id, 'edit'). '</td>';
```

but i'm confused on how can i add the rel and class tag. also the button
by the way i'm using bootstrap and 'facebox' is a jquery dialog box so when i clicked the button a dialog box will appear with the information about that user.

I hope someone might help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
echo anchor("useredit.php?emp_id=". $row['emp_id']", "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>", "rel='Facebox'");
```

Also you have incorrect closing a tag and td

Answer (score 0):

From the CodeIgniter user guide:

-anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)

-The third parameter can contain a list of attributes you would like added to the link. The attributes can be a simple string or an associative array.

So you could do:
`$args = array("rel"=>"content","target"=>"_blank", "class"=>"your_class");`

Link: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the anchor function in CodeIgniter, you must first load the URL helper either by adding it to the list of autoloaded helpers or by putting `$this->load->helper('url');` in your controller before the anchor function is called.

You would then use `echo '<td>'.anchor('useredit.php?emp_id='.$row['emp_id'], '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>', 'rel="Facebox"').'</td>';`

The anchor function takes 3 arguments. The first (`'useredit.php?emp_id='.$row['emp_id']`) is the relative link which you would normally put in the href attribute. The second is the html you want to appear between the anchor tags (`'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>'`) and the third contains other html attributes you want to apply to the anchor such as an id, class or target attribute. In your case, you only need to add `'rel="Facebox"'`.

Referring to the manual for Facebox at http://defunkt.io/facebox/ shows that you would load jQuery and the css and js for Facebox and then use the following in a javascript file to attach Facebox to the link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples taken from [URL Helper : CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

This:

```
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', 'title="News title"');
```

Would produce:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123" title="News title">My News</a>
```

And this:

```
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', array('title' => 'The best news!'));
```

Would produce:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123" title="The best news!">My News</a>
```

So, in your case, you could do something like:

```
echo '<td>' . anchor('useredit.php?emp_id=' . $row['emp_id'], '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>', 'rel="whatever_you_want_here"') . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
<td>
<?php $style='<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>'; echo anchor('useredit.php?emp_id='.$row['emp_id'],$style,'rel="facebox"');?>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not mess up with the complex functions in this stage, because you are new.

just place your code like this bellow.

`echo '<td><a rel="facebox" href=user_controller/user_edit/'. $row['emp_id'] .'><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></td></a>' ;`

```
 Class user_controller extends CI_Controller{
      function user_edit($userid){
          echo $userid;
          // you can find the user Id in this way and continue your editing
      }
 }
```